# How can i copy my Magento files

Tags: file, magento, copy

I had an assignment in magento. I installed magento without sample data. I completed assignment tast in default magento setting. now i want to send this solution to my teacher. which files i should copy and send him so that it will work fine.

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Send to him whatever files created or edited, keep the folder structure the same as from the installation folder of Magento.

Comment: i am new to magento, if i compress app folder of magento, its 9mb, and can't send him

Comment: only the files that you (yourself) created or editted, and keep the correct folder structure before zipping

Comment: thanks once again, i added a catogary menu. than added 5 products those are displayed when i click this menu. i do not know which files i created. i just added products from admin panal and added an extra attribute sort_text. what i should copy in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to archive the whole Magento folder and make a dump of the database.
Put those 2 files together and upload them to some cyberlocker like mediafire or something.
If you added attributes you will need to provide with the database (unless you have written a module with an install script that automatically makes the changes.)

Give that link to your teacher ;)

PS: You could always just contact your teacher and ask him how he wants to have your solution.

Comment: Can you help me, how to debug magento code. I have configured xdebug and installed phpstorm, i tried much to debug the code. can you tell me how to connect phpstorm and magento code...if possible?

Comment: I would just use notepad or another lightweight editor to code. (Magento is a large solution code-wise, IMO too heavy for PHPStorm).

Comment: can you help me how to add a button on frontend like we do <input type=button> in html. i want to add a button on front end and when user click on this button, it should sort the products on page dsc order? I have tried much , where to add html and how to write php code to do it... if you can please help me.